# iText 5.1.2 does not flatten text boxes

Tags: java, pdf, itext, adobe, flatten

I'm using iText 5.1.2 - importing a pdf that has been created in this way -

- Open any pdf in Adobe Reader
- Go to the View menu
- Choose Fill & Sign
- Choose to Add Text
- Enter text in a text box on the page
- Save the file

When I run that pdf through the following method, the resulting pdf does not include the text that was input into the text box -

```
public static void flatten( File _src, File _dest ) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        PdfReader reader = null;
        PdfStamper stamper = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try{
        fos = new FileOutputStream( _dest );
        reader = new PdfReader( _src.getAbsolutePath() );
        stamper = new PdfStamper( reader, fos );
        stamper.setFormFlattening( true );

        stamper.close();
    }finally{
        if ( reader != null ) reader.close();
        if ( fos != null ) try{ fos.close(); }catch( IOException ignored ){}
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A text box annotation is not a form field. Hence form flattening does not apply to text box annotations.

Comment: OK, then how do I ensure that the text in text boxes transfers to the new pdf on the other end? If setFormFlattening does not achieve this, then what else should I be doing?

Comment: You should start by using a current software version. 5.1.2 is ancient and many improvements habe been made since then.

Comment: I think that @mkl might be right. I think that flattening annotations was introduced! after a customer's request at some point. Are you a customer? Also: why would you neec the annotations to be flattened to "transfer it to another PDF"??? That sounds like you're doing something seriously wrong.

Comment: more like convert than transfer. we take a document, flatten it, then add header and footer information to it. and take multiple documents and stitch them together. the documents come from many different users across the country and are not standard forms by any means.

Answer (score -1):

setting setAnnotationFlattening as true is going to solve the text boxes flattening.

stamper.setAnnotationFlattening(true)

Comment: it was outlined by other user, that the version 5.1.2 is ancient and does not support annotation flattening. It was also mentioned, that the question refers to a problem that should not be solved by this approach anyway. Please take this into account and provide some context, if you feel the need to answer such an old question.